# Sqsh, выполнить запрос из файла

Tags: linux, sql-server

Установил пакет `mssql-server`, версия 14.0.3006.16-3 на ***debian stretch***( 9.1 ) из официальной репы. Всё встало нормально с учётом бэкпортов из ***jessie***. С помощью `sqsh` создал базу `testdb`. Далее пытался влить схему из файла, но попытка не увенчалась успехом. При этом нет никаких ошибок в консоли, логов тоже нет.

```
>sqsh -S localhost -U sa -P <password> -i /home/andrey/schema
```

Содержимое файла:

```
USE testdb
GO

CREATE TABLE test (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
);
GO
```

У утилиты не обнаружил ключей типа *verbose*, а ключ `-l All`( полный debug ) не работает, нужно перекомпилировать сам `sqsh`. В sql-клиенте( использую `dbeaver` ) могу схему создать, но после нужно будет вливать данные, которых не мало, хотелось бы через консоль стандартными средствами.
Может кто знает в чём проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `USE testdb` — а что, создавать базу данных не надо?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin __jessie. С помощью sqsh создал базу testdb. Далее__

Answer (score 0):

Помимо лишних знаков препинания( запятая после `PRIMARY KEY`, точка с запятой ), которые парсер благополучно съедает без последствий( проверено практически ), основной проблемой была команда `go` в верхнем регистре. Перевод из `GO` -> в `go` решил проблему.

[Источник](https://sourceforge.net/p/sqsh/discussion/365923/thread/bb430f24/)(перевод google translate):

> Вы должны различать команды sqsh и команды SQL. Команды Sqsh действительно чувствительны к регистру. Команда «go» является псевдонимом для команды «\go» и также чувствительна к регистру.

Для небольшой автоматизации можно создать алиас:

```
echo \\alias GO=\\go >> ~/.sqshrc
```